# Various SSAS Tabular Error Messages That Make No Sense

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, dax, ssas-tabular

I've had an SSAS tabular model deployed to a server running SQL Server 2016 for about a month and it has been running fine.  All of a sudden, today it is throwing random errors when I try to query it.  I just tried to run the same query 8 times and got the following 8 error messages:

1) An unexpected error occurred (file 'xmvsquery.cpp', line 3184, function 'XMVSColumn::Bind').

2) An unexpected exception occurred.

3) Query (7, 46) A date column containing duplicate dates was specified in the call to function 'DATESYTD'. This is not supported.

4) Memory error: Allocation failure . If using a 32-bit version of the product, consider upgrading to the 64-bit version or increasing the amount of memory available on the machine.

5) Column 'RowNumber-2662979B-1795-4F74-8F37-6A1BA8059B61' in table 'table name' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.

6) An unexpected error occurred (file 'tmmdmodeltm.cpp', line 2404, function 'MDModelTM::ResolveIMBIColumnId').

7) MdxScript(Model) (1, 66) Calculation error in measure 'measure name': A date column containing duplicate dates was specified in the call to function 'DATESYTD'. This is not supported.

8) Column 'RowNumber-2662979B-1795-4F74-8F37-6A1BA8059B61' in table 'table name' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.

Looking in the application log on the server yields no further information - The description for Event ID 22 from source MSSQLServerOLAPService cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

A couple of things that are interesting.  The errors only happen if I try to run an MDX query against the model.  If I try to run an equivalent DAX query, it runs fine.  If I clear the SSAS cache, I can run the MDX and DAX queries against the model for a short period of time before this starts happening again.

This model is currently deployed to Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB3207512) - 13.0.4199.0 (X64) and the server is running Windows Server 2016.

I've tried the following so far, and after doing each it will work for a short period of time and then it starts up again

- Redeploy the model
- Delete the database completely and redploy the model
- Do a full process of the model
- Clear the SSAS cache

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you googled? https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3104745/an-unexpected-error-occurred-file-xmvsquery-cpp-line-3184-function-xmvscolumn-bind-causes-ssas-tabular-2016-to-crash

Comment: I did see that but it did not apply, there was no migration involved here.  After I posted this question I did end up stumbling on someone who was having almost the same issue (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3110738/ssas-2016-tabular-corrupt-cube-cache-an-unexpected-exception-occurred).  I applied the most recent CU update (build 13.0.4411.0) and hoping that works.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to be like your are experiencing the same defect I ran into with 2016 SP1-RTM - a seemingly random pattern of unexpected exceptions, queries that would sometimes run, sometimes not, or even render the database unprocessed(!).

[SP1-CU2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013106/cumulative-update-2-for-sql-server-2016-sp1) resolves a number of defects which can cause symptoms like you are seeing (see link for full list), so if you've now got the latest update you are probably OK.

The only defect I have seen which SP1-CU2 does not resolve is that [SELECTCOLUMNS() does not play nicely with UNION()](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3133975/ssas-tabular-2016-sp1-cu2-selectcolumns-may-return-incorrect-results-in-multigrain-union-queries).